# SCP permission denied when copying from server to local

Tags: ssh, scp

So I am setting up a vpn and I keep getting a permission denied error when I use `scp`. I've tried several methods (the ones I found online) but nothing seems to help.

```
root@debian-512mb-fra1-01: scp root@server:textfilepath ~/Desktop << desktop of local machine
Permission denied (publickey).
```

@waltinator moved this from the comment, so it could be formatted.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: No more authentication methods to try. 
Permission denied (publickey). 
nizar@debian-512mb-fra1-01:~$
```

Comment: I've tried everything, changed local permissions, deleted droplet and created new one, copied ssh keys from local to server... literally everything, changed the syntax a couple of times but still the same error

Comment: Is `server` running Ubuntu? if not, this question is off-topic. Basically the error indicates either that `server` is not configured to allow ssh/scp for `root`, or the keys were incorrectly generated / copied / installed (often it is a matter of over-permissive permissions on the key files or their parent directories). Running `scp` with extra verbosity (`-v`) may help to narrow it down.

Comment: debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nizar/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
nizar@debian-512mb-fra1-01:~$

Comment: yes ubuntu... what rsa key is it looking for here? every single rsa key on my local machine is on my server. is it looking for something else?

Comment: It's looking for something else. Use `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id` to copy keys, read `man ssh-copy-id`. It wants the keys in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I already did that, now theres a new problem :( scp doesnt send the file to my local machine, instead it creates a directory on my server (the one I'm trying to send from)

Comment: You are not consistent. On the two snippets, one says your user is `nizar`, on the other one `root`.  What is the user you are connecting? Where do you run the command? What is the key that "should work"?